# How to use a SOCKS5 Proxy in Unix

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, udp, socks5-proxy

I have a python bot which works on UDP Protocol. I know that only SOCKS5 Proxies support UDP, but how do I use them?

I have seen many tutorials but they're using ssh to connect to remote and that's something I don't want to do
I think some Proxifier might work but proxychains is not working. Somehow the bot gives out a UDP access error.

Please help me out

Comment: This should be useful:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7652449/understanding-the-socks5-protocol

Comment: But how do I use the proxy?